# salesforce get token using jQuery ajax method

Tags: jquery, salesforce, access-token

I have just intigrated the salseforce api using curl in php and its working fine but now i have to using the same thing with ajax so no curl is used here below is my code

```
var param = {
grant_type: "password",
client_id : "CLIENT_ID",
client_secret : "CLIENT_SECRET",
username:"USERNAME",
password:"PASSWORD"};
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
        type: 'POST',
        data: param,
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('Successfully retrieved ' + response);
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        }

    });
```

when i alert the response than showing below response

[image]

and when inspect the response then showing below response

[image]

Please help me what's wrong and how to solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: By the way, salesforce professionals are in [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: should i ask same question there

Comment: I think it would be much promising.

Comment: Thanks you just add the same question there

Comment: How did you fix the error

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice to expose this secrets in java script variables. Please have a look at my blog and try to authenticate using APEX which is server side validation. In my blog I have shown a secure way to connect with Salesforce API using Auth provider and named credientials where no one sees the password and not stored anywhere.

If you follow the approach authtication will be done by salesforce no extra code required you can call any Salesforce API. but it will be serverside only.

But if you want to do it from client side you can get help from here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm

https://avionsalesforce.blogspot.com/2022/01/salesforce-to-salesforce-connection.html

Sallesforce help document

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_about.htm&type=5